# SQL: Finding duplicate entry in library database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to check if any book id and/or book code is a duplicate for a unique StudentVisitId and it should return a single row. If a duplicate is found, then it should return 0 else 1.

**Data:**

```
BookID  StudentVisitId  BookCode    ListOrder
42568   4531            B1162       3
42568   4531            B1162       2
64532   4531            B1178       2
64532   4598            B1178       3
76543   4622            B1178       2
64532   4622            B1178       1
```

**Expected output:**

```
StudentVisitId  DuplicateEntry
4531            0
4598            1
4622            1
```

`0` indicates `StudentVisitId` `4531` is a duplicate for `BookId` `42568` and `BookCode` `B1162`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT StudentVisitId, MIN(DuplicateEntry) DuplicateEntry
FROM (
    SELECT BookID,  StudentVisitId,  BookCode, DuplicateEntry = (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
    FROM @DATA
    GROUP BY BookID,  StudentVisitId,  BookCode 
) AS A
GROUP BY StudentVisitId
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in many ways. Below SQL shows how to achieve this using CTE

```
;
WITH CTE(StudentVisitId, DuplicateEntry)
AS
(
SELECT StudentVisitId,
       CASE 
       WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BookId, StudentVisitId, BookCode ORDER BY StudentVisitId) > 1 
       THEN 0 ELSE 1 
       END 
FROM LibraryData
)SELECT StudentVisitId, MIN(DuplicateEntry) FROM cte 
GROUP BY StudentVisitId
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
select studentid,
       (case when min(bookcode) = max(bookcode) then 1 else 0 end) as isDuplicate
from t
group by studentid;
```

I'm not exactly sure what `isDuplicate` really means in this case.  That seems like an odd name for the column.  A better name would be `hasOnlyOneBook`.

Comment: Case statement is giving opposite answers. But when I interchanged the values 1 and 0, it worked well.